# Understanding the dynamics implementation (rigid, soft body and Force Fields)

Tags: particles, physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body, force-fields

i'm currenty studying the blender dynamics and physics implementation for research purpose, but i'm struggling to do so. I've already searched extensively in the documentation pages but still I haven't found a more in depth description on how the developers implemented those functionalities, neither I'm able to grasp a general understanding of the system.

The core components I'm researching are Rigid Body, Soft Body and Force Fields.
While i've got confirmation that Rigid Body is handled by the Bullet physics engine, looking at the source code i've realized that the Soft Body is internally developed, and still I cannot figure how those two systems interact with each other, with the Force Fields effecting also both of them. 
What do you suggest I should look into, to grasp some more information about that?
If you happen to know any of this, how would you summarize the interaction between forces, rigid body, soft bodys and particles so I can go and look how each component is made?

I was also wondering if there's some documentation on the original papers by which those implementations were inspired, but the only piece of evidence i've found so far is some link to the "Fast Simulation of Mass-Spring Systems" paper, from which I guess the devs wrote the code for the deformable meshes

Comment: Rigid Bodies and Softbodies don't interact (sadly).

Comment: @Leander that's another piece of the puzzle, thanks :)